# Suggested way to write a queryset to Parquet in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have a query that runs against a SQL Server instance that takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 75 minutes to complete. The response size is anywhere from a few rows to 1GB of data. I have a parquet writer that only has to wait until the query completes and results sent back and it will write the results to Google Cloud Storage.

What would be the best product to accomplish this, and is their one that would have roughly zero startup time? The two that came to mind for me were Cloud Functions and Cloud Run, but I've never used either.

Answer (score 1):

Neither service meets your requirement of 75 minutes.

Cloud Functions times out at 540 seconds.

[Cloud Functions Time Limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits)

Cloud Run times out at 60 minutes.

[Cloud Run Request Timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout)

For that sort of runtime, I would launch a container in Compute Engine Container-Optimized OS.

[Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs)

There is the possibility of configuring Cloud Run **cpu-throttling** so that you can run tasks in the background.

[Run more workloads on Cloud Run with new CPU allocation controls](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation)

Note that you will be paying for the service on a constant basis as it is no longer running services (containers) on demand.